# Setting (Max) height for the table-cells

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

EDIT: **ANSWER FOUND** IN COMMENTS! **Thanks**! ;)

---

I need some **vertically** middle-aligned text, having a maximal height limit (say 60px)
[image]

The problem is that I can't set a height to a `table-cell`.

From the other part, if I have no `table-cell` I have no middle-alignment.

How to solve this problem ?

Bellow is my code (CodePen [HERE](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/ZemNLe))

```css
.row { width: 900px; }
.row > div {display: table; }
.row > div > div {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 1em;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:green">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60?text=60">
  <div style="background: yellow"> 1Middle-vertical text green-yel </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:green">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60?text=60">
  <div style="background: yellow"> 1Middle-vertical text green-yel 2Middle-vertical text green-yel </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:red">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60?text=!60">
  <div style="background: yellow"> 1Middle-vertical text red-yel 2Middle-vertical text red-yel 3Middle-vertical text red-yel 4Middle-vertical text red-yel </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at the inline-block and vertical alignment. https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA

Comment: you could wrap the content of the table cell in another div and set it's max-height. Take a look at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZdvKa.

Comment: Try using inline-block and vertical align: http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/ryoKVM

Comment: @TommySchmidt, thanks, man, you are my hero!

Comment: this could also be solved by using flexbox: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMoYjM. i just want to give you another option because i don't like how we used `display: table` here.

Comment: @TommySchmidt I need compatibility with the IE9... (